# Enforcing referential integrity on among distantly related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-normalization, referential-integrity

I have a four tables, which look a bit like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableA]
    ( [ID]    INT     NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY )
CREATE TABLE [TableB]
    ( [A_ID]  INT     NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [TableA] ([ID]) 
    , [Value] TINYINT NOT NULL 
    , PRIMARY KEY ( [A_ID], [Value] ) )
CREATE TABLE [TableC]
    ( [ID]    INT     NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [A_ID]  INT     NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [TableA] ([ID]) )
CREATE TABLE [TableD]
    ( [ID]    INT     NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [C_ID]  INT     NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [TableC] ([ID])
    , [Value] TINYINT NOT NULL )
```

But I'd like to enforce referential integrity on `TableD` such that a valid value may only be one of the values from `TableB` of the `TableA` associated with the parent `TableC` record. For example:

```
TableA: ID 
         1
TableB: A_ID | VALUE
           1 |     1
           1 |     2
TableC: ID | A_ID
         7 |    1
TableD: ID | C_ID | VALUE
         1 |    7 |     1 -- Fine, Inserted
         1 |    7 |     2 -- Fine, Inserted
         1 |    7 |     3 -- Invalid, Rejected!
```

Now, I tried adding an `A_ID` column to `TableD` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableD]
    ( [ID]    INT     NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [C_ID]  INT     NOT NULL 
    , [A_ID]  INT     NOT NULL 
    , [Value] TINYINT NOT NULL
    , FOREIGN KEY ([C_ID], [A_ID]) REFERENCES [TableC] ([ID], [A_ID])
    , FOREIGN KEY ([A_ID], [Value]) REFERENCES [TableB] ([A_ID], [Value]) )
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table '`TableC`' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key '`FK__TableD__TableC`'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I don't really like this solution anyway because it seems denormalized—since I have the `TableC`→`TableA` relationship stored in two different places—but I can't think of any other way to enforce referential integrity (other than triggers, which I'd like to avoid).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: that's not what foreign keys are for. they're just there to check if a parent record exists. Not to enforce a particular ancestry count. You want a `check` constraint instead.

Comment: @MarcB can you provide an example?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @MarcB I saw that, but I'm not sure how to apply it in my case. It can't just be a simple function call, it would have to be something like `CHECK ([Value] IN (SELECT [Value] FROM [TableB] ... ))`

Comment: those functions can be stored procedures. the only restriction is that the function you use (or create) returns true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can add `unique` constraint to table `TableC`:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableC]
    ( [ID]    INT     NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [A_ID]  INT     NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [TableA] ([ID]),
     CONSTRAINT UK_TableC UNIQUE ([ID], [A_ID]) )
```

and then you will be able referencing `TableC` in table `TableD` as you specified:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableD]
    ( [ID]    INT     NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [C_ID]  INT     NOT NULL 
    , [A_ID]  INT     NOT NULL 
    , [Value] TINYINT NOT NULL
    , FOREIGN KEY ([C_ID], [A_ID]) REFERENCES [TableC] ([ID], [A_ID])
    , FOREIGN KEY ([A_ID], [Value]) REFERENCES [TableB] ([A_ID], [Value]) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try this out (as well as Marc B's suggestion) as soon as I can.

Comment: This works. It's strange that I have to add a unique constraint. Since `ID` is the primary key any pair of columns including `ID` is guaranteed to be unique, but I suppose that's SQL. I've also managed to get Mark B's suggestion working as well, but I'm not sure which one I prefer. This seems more reliable since breaking changes in `TableB` will automatically be rejected thanks to the FK on `TableD`, but the check condition appears to preserve normalization. Perhaps that's a question for another day.